# How to rename Google Drive file with Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

how are you doing?

I'm trying to rename some files in my Google Drive folder, [following the instructions listed in documentation.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update?)
However I'm getting an error in one of the arguments (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trying_new_filename_string')

I ONLY NEED TO RENAME THE DOCUMENT, NOTHING ELSE.

This is my code:

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
file_id = '1TKxcYDzEK3SUjSv6dCMM6WkKRmZwm84SPWVhR1F2DEc'
new_title = 'trying_new_title'
new_mime_type = 'trying_new_mime_type'
new_filename = 'trying_new_filename_string'


from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


def update_file(service, file_id, new_title, new_mime_type, new_filename):
    
    # First retrieve the file from the API.
    file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()

    # File's new metadata.
    file['name'] = new_title
    file['mimeType'] = new_mime_type

    # File's new content.
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(
        new_filename, mimetype=new_mime_type, resumable=True)

    # Send the request to the API.
    updated_file = service.files().update(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=file,
        media_body=media_body).execute()
    return updated_file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems related to the fact the `new_filename` does not exist. As the [`MediaUploadFile`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload-class.html) tries to open and does not find a file with the `trying_new_filename_string` name.

As you only need to rename that file, don't change its content, you should remove the `MediaUploadFile` method.

Try:

```py
def renameFile(service, fileId, newTitle):
    body = {'name': newTitle}
    return service.files().update(fileId=fileId, body=body).execute()
```